# Ctrl-S in console not working. It seems to be waiting on input

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm trying to make a console application in *C#*. When using `Console.ReadKey` and typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> the application seems to be "waiting" on another keypress because the next key I type also gets eaten.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging the only way I could figure out how to do this is to call some native methods to disable `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT`. I don't know why this works because the docs for `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` say:

> The ReadFile or ReadConsole function returns only when a carriage return character is read. If this mode is disabled, the functions return when one or more characters are available.

Which doesn't really seem related. Especially since `ReadKey` doesn't wait for `return` anyways.

Maybe someone else can explain it better?

Code:

```
int mode = 0;
GetConsoleMode(handle, ref mode);
mode &= ~0x0002; // Disable ENABLE_LINE_INPUT.  Lets ctrl-s work for some reason.
SetConsoleMode(handle, mode);
```